# Collision detection with JavaScript. (Check if 2 Block Level elements are touching)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want To check if my div have touch another div

here is my Work

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
        if(getmouse){
            var newX= event.pageX-20;
            var newY= event.pageY-20;
            $('.mybox').css('left',newX + "px");
            $('.mybox').css('top',newY+ "px");
            var checkY = parseInt($('.box1').css('top').slice(0,-2));
            var checkX = parseInt($('.box1').css('left').slice(0,-2));
            var padingval = parseInt($('.box').css('padding').slice(0,-2))*2;
            console.log(checkY+padingval+" - "+newY);
            if((newY==checkY&&newX==checkX)||newY+20<checkY-padingval
               ||newY-20<checkY+padingval)
            {
                alert('Game Over');
                getmouse = false;
                $('.mybox').css('top',"240px");
                $('.mybox').css('left',"420px");
            }
        }
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/48m6rof6

if My div Touch any div it Must alert Game over and return to its place
I have checked if it touched first box but if there is any simple way to check ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Jquery collision plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/) like this:

```
var x = $("#div1").collision(".div2");
```

Comment: is there any documentation for it ?

Comment: @IslamZedan:- The description section has the details about it! Also go to the respective tabs which are there in the link for details like http://sourceforge.net/p/jquerycollision/wiki/Home/